# Mongocxx How can I access the view from the cursor faster

Tags: c++, mongodb-query, aggregate, mongo-cxx-driver

I have an opencv code and it needs to run very fast, faster than all loops in opencv. That's why I added most of the processes to the database, but when everything is very fast, accessing the view from the cursor is slow, according to the opencv codes.

I want to reach the view from the cursor faster. Is there any other way around this?
For example, can I write a function or something so that mongocxx returns direct view to me?

I did the following operations. I share the operations with their elapsed time. I would be very happy if you can help.

```
    void MongoDB::SecondPointIteration(cv::KeyPoint&keypoints, SecondIterParams& secondIterParams ){

auto start1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); 

    secondParams = secondIterParams;  
    mongocxx::pipeline secondIterPipeline = setSorgu();
    mongocxx::cursor cursor = features.aggregate(secondIterPipeline, mongocxx::options::aggregate{});

auto end1  = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end1-start1).count();
std::cout<<"2.1:   \t"<< time<<"ms"<<std::endl;
    
auto start3 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); 
    for(auto&& doc : cursor) {      
    auto end3  = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto time3 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end3-start3).count();
    std::cout<<"2.2.1:   \t"<< time3<<"ms"<<std::endl;

    auto start2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        ...
        keypoints.response = doc["_id"]["response"].get_double().value; 

    auto end2  = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto time2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end2-start2).count();
    std::cout<<"2.2.2:   \t"<< time2<<"ms"<<std::endl;

    }
auto end3  = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto time3 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end3-start3).count();
std::cout<<"2.2:   \t"<< time3<<"ms"<<std::endl;  


}
mongocxx::pipeline  MongoDB::setSorgu(){
    using namespace bsoncxx::builder::basic;
    mongocxx::pipeline secondIterPipeline{};

    ...

    secondIterPipeline.sort(make_document(kvp("_id.response", -1)));
    secondIterPipeline.limit(1);

    return secondIterPipeline;
}
```

Elapsed times are written by matching std :: cout

```
1:      761ms
2.1:    80ms
2.2.1:          1150ms
2.2.2:          2ms
2.2:    1158ms
```

The number 1 represents the time taken by opencv loops

My database contains similar data such as

```
    [{

  "keypoint": {
    "response": 0
  }
},{
  "keypoint": {
    "response": 0.0010120292427018285
  }
},{
  "keypoint": {

    "response": 0.0017831606091931462
  }
}]
```

Comment: Are you using an embedded data model or a normalized one? "_Combine objects into one document if you will use them together. Otherwise separate them (but make sure there should not be need of joins)._" and "_Do joins while write, not on read_" etc. from [MongoDB - Data Modelling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_data_modeling.htm)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hi, I update the question, I hope it is the answer to what you asked.